# Failed to enable constraints?

Tags: c#, sql

ERROR: **Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.**

Any one a solution for this problem? 
I try to merge a view into a dataSet.
Here is my view and it's result.

[IMAGE LINK](http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/5475/screendrh.png)

[image]

Comment: One solution would be using something than ADO.NET `DataSet`s, like any number of ORM's available (Entity Framework, LINQ to SQL, NHibernate, etc.)

Comment: We use Datasets over the whole project so I'm not able to change that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try disabling constraints on the dataset as so:

```
dataSet1.EnforceConstraints = false;
```

And then fill it.